# For startActivity, ActivityManager Log is showing, but is not calling activity's onCreate

Tags: android, kotlin, android-service, android-logcat, android-wear-2.0

I'm trying to start an activity from accessibility service. 
So in my app, this is the one and only activity.
When I called `startActivity()`, the below log is printed, but will not call activity(which is named WifiAlertDialouge)'s `onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)`.

```
I/ActivityManager: START u0 {flg=0x50000000 cmp=com.estimote.indoorapp/.WifiAlertDialouge} from uid 10065 on display 0
```

What does the above log mean? Does it mean that activity is starting?
Any guess on why my activity's `onCreate` is not being called?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that it was because I was trying to start activity inside a `for` loop. I found that starting activity would work if it is outside the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to start the activity from a service, you should add the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` flag

```
Intent dialogIntent = new Intent(this, WifiAlertDialouge.class);
dialogIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(dialogIntent);
```